# How to I set the permissions necessary to make the ioctl CDROM_SEND_PACKET command run?

Tags: linux, devices, ioctl

I've run into an error stemming from lacking permissions when using the CDIO library to issue an eject command to my USB CD-ROM drive. I always get an error message like this:

```
INFO: ioctl CDROM_SEND_PACKET for command PREVENT ALLOW MEDIUM REMOVAL (0x1e) failed: Operation not permitted
```

The `ioctl` call is part of the `cdda-player` app I call as follows:

```
cdda-player -ev /dev/sr0
```

After taking a look into the [sourcecode](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/libcdio.git/tree/lib/driver/gnu_linux.c?id=release-2.1.0#n1245) of `libcdio`, I found out that this line of code makes trouble:

```c
int i_rc = ioctl (p_env->gen.fd, CDROM_SEND_PACKET, &cgc);
```

When I run the code as root (using `sudo`), everything works fine. Here are the permissions for my CD-ROM drive:

```
pi@autoradio:/import/valen/autoradio/libcdio-master $ ls -al /dev/sr0 
brw-rw----+ 1 root cdrom 11, 0 Jul  5 22:42 /dev/sr0

pi@autoradio:/import/valen/autoradio/libcdio-master $ ls -al /dev/sg0 
crw-rw----+ 1 root cdrom 21, 0 Jul  5 22:38 /dev/sg0

pi@autoradio:~ $ getfacl /dev/sr0 
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names 
# file: dev/sr0 
# owner: root 
# group: cdrom 
user::rw- 
user:pi:rw- 
group::rw- 
mask::rw- 
other::---
```

The user `pi` is part of the `cdrom` group. The standard `eject` utility does work, though.

Now: Which permissions do I have to set for the eject operation to work as an ordinary user? Thank you.

**UPDATE:** Here is my kernel version:

```
pi@autoradio:/import/valen/autoradio/libcdio-master $ uname -a 
Linux autoradio 4.9.35-v7+ #1014 SMP Fri Jun 30 14:47:43 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Huh. I think it should only require write access. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.1/source/block/scsi_ioctl.c#L204 (see also https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.1/source/block/scsi_ioctl.c#L595 ).  What is your kernel version?

Comment: Quick check: if you run `strace -e trace=%file cdda-player -ev /dev/sr0`, does it open() `/dev/sr0` as `O_RDWR`, or does it use `O_RDONLY`?

Comment: `strace` returns a syntax error here: `invalid system call '%file'`

Comment: frickin deprecation cycles. hopefully `strace -e trace=file ...` will work on your system. on newer systems you're supposed to use `%file`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after a hint from one of the maintainers of `libcdio`, I found out that the version I installed was out of date and contained a bug based on improper use of `O_RDWR` vs. `O_RDONLY`. After the update, suddenly everything works fine. Nevertheless thank you for your hints!